# Android program to connect Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfid

I have Bluetooth device called FEIG OBID iScan - HF reader which will connect to PC through Bluetooth and send the data when reads HF tag.I have paired the device in my Android phone and generated code like
00:07:80:9C:C9:B9 now through my andriod program **how can I connect** to this  device and **get the data from the device**(FEIG) in to android device.Please give any android source code to connect and get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years ago I also tried to connect using bluetooh on my PC and send data to a terminal and also to a bluetooh module and I managed to do that using the following example:

[Bluetooh chat example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat)

(of course you need to adapt it to your needs)

The example above contains a server and a client that will send and receive messages/data using bluetooh connection, it will also show you how to search for devices and pair them.

I also found this example and I think it will also be useful to see and understand.
[Android--Bluetooth-Connection-Code-Sample](https://github.com/theappguruz/Android--Bluetooth-Connection-Code-Sample)

Cheers

Comment: I have checked those link source codes however I want devices to connect automatically without when ever those two are in range or from the Android device I should be able select the device then the connection should happened without acknowledgement or without accept request

Comment: Hmmm...I dont think that is posible because you need to pair the devices first, If you want to find those devices after you paired them, I think you should make a Service class and ierate the paired devices (I dont recommand this option becuase It will consume a lot of resources)

Comment: YES,I want it for only paired devices, please share if you have any source code to connect the paired devices without accept request(it is fine even with any service also)

Comment: Basically what I want is I am able to pair my HF device with android device, but as I am using Bluetooth chat apk to get the data from HF device, when I am trying to connect to HF device not connecting,might be expecting to get the connection request from HF device also or excepting to accept the request.so i want direct connection after pairing.

Comment: please help me out this is urgent for me, as I am new to android not able to move forward